# string format en un input que recibe valor de ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un  textbox,  el cual recibe un dato por AJAX.

```html
@Html.TextBox("CantidadPago", string.Format("{0:C}",0), new{@class = "form-control"})
```

**AJAX**

```html
$.ajax({ 
       type: 'POST', 
       url: '@Url.Action("CalcularCantidadPago")', 
       datatype: 'json', 
       data: {totalC: $("#Total").val()},
       success: function (Precios) { 
       $("#CantidadPago").val(Precios[0]); },

});
```

Y pues me sale asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y lo que quiero es darle formato. Algo así :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté con `string.Format("{0:C}",0)`, pero cuando le asigno el valor traído al textbox me borra el formato.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacerle para que al recibir el dato me conserve el formato y al enviarlo no afecte mi operación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías formatearlo antes de setearle el valor al input con jquery, seria algo así:

```
$.ajax({ 
   type: 'POST', 
   url: '@Url.Action("CalcularCantidadPago")', 
   datatype: 'json', 
   data: {totalC: $("#Total").val()},
   success: function (Precios) { 
   $("#CantidadPago").val('$' + parseFloat(Precios[0]).toFixed(2)); },
});
```